# Phoenix can't start - Missing AppName.Endpoint.start_link

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Pheonix changes so frequently that I'm not sure that what I'm doing is right.

I'm trying to follow some tutorials, and all of them have the 'mix phoenix.start' command right after you finish compiling and that should start the server.  (There is some talk on the issues page of Github that they are going to replace that with the mix phoenix.server command and you have to do something manually, not really following it.  Anyways, that is in the development version v0.8.0-dev.  I'm using the latest stable version 0.7.2)

I'm getting an error trying to issue the 'mix phoenix.start' command trying to start the server
(AppName: PhoenixCrud):

```
> mix phoenix.start

=INFO REPORT==== 13-Dec-2014::15:23:08 ===
    application: logger
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary

=INFO REPORT==== 13-Dec-2014::15:23:08 ===
    application: cowboy
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary

=INFO REPORT==== 13-Dec-2014::15:23:08 ===
    application: cowlib
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary

=INFO REPORT==== 13-Dec-2014::15:23:08 ===
    application: ranch
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary
** (Mix) Could not start application phoenix_crud: PhoenixCrud.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: PhoenixCrud.Endpoint
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: PhoenixCrud.Endpoint.start_link/0
            (phoenix_crud) PhoenixCrud.Endpoint.start_link()
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:314: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:297: :supervisor.start_children/3
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:263: :supervisor.init_children/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:306: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:237: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

The docs have the updated phoenix.server command, but I tried that also, and that mix says that the task could not be found.

Anyways, it looks as if the *app_name*/lib/*app_name*/endpoint.ex is missing a start_link function.  Am I supposed to provide that?  I have no idea right now what to put in because I'm just trying out the Phoenix web framework and don't know anything about it (hence the tutorials.)

So, am I supposed to provide the start_link function, if so, can some give me some to stub in for now to try to follow some tutorials. Otherwise is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My git knowledge is not that great, but here goes:

To use 0.7.2 branch, you need to specifically checkout v0.7.2 tag.
So this is how I did it:

```
git clone https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix.git
cd phoenix
git checkout tags/v0.7.2
mix do deps.get, compile
mix phoenix.new app_name ../app_name
cd ../app_name
#change the mix deps to: (I think you can just use default hex deps as well)
{:phoenix, github: "phoenixframework/phoenix", tag: "v0.7.2"}
mix do deps.get, compile
mix phoenix.start
```

Otherwise, the Phoenix code that you normally git clone is on the master branch is on 0.8.0-dev, which you will need to set the deps to the github master branch (as stated by @JoseValim)

```
{:phoenix, github: "phoenixframework/phoenix"}
```

Which means, you now need to use the mix phoenix.server command.

Hope that helps others.

Answer (score 5):

It is a Phoenix version thing. The endpoint is only available in master, but it seems you are not using master. You should either add `{:phoenix, github: "phoenixframework/phoenix"}` to your `mix.exs` or generate a Phoenix project from the 0.7.2 branch.

Comment: I was using the 0.7.2 branch from hex.  Now I just changed it to the github master branch and it worked.  But it's confusing because I'm thinking that the master branch is on v0.8.0-dev, because I have to use `mix phoenix.server` to start it.  According to the changelog: [https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) , it is the v0.8.0-dev which first changes it to use mix phoenix.server vs mix phoenix.start

Comment: This pisses me off. Why I can't just run a version that I already have? Anybody has a good explanation? Now I can't run my 1.1.4 version, and I guess that I have to update to 1.2. But this update will push me to update phoenix_ecto to > '3.0'. And I have a bunch of other deps that requires phoenix_ecto v2. The question is: I had it all working and running, than reloaded pc and now I have to spend a lot of time to fix all deps to just run my project. Why?

Comment: @AvaelKross I literally have no idea what you are talking about. As long as your check your `mix.lock` into your source control (and you should), every time you run `mix deps.get` you will get the exact same version you got the last time you used it, be it last week or back in 2014.

Comment: @AvaelKross and to further clarify, this issue happened only in the past because we didn't have a proper `phoenix.new`. So people would generate a new application using 0.8.0-dev but the only available version was 0.7.2. It definitely shouldn't happen today.

Comment: @JoséValim Thanks for the answer. To be honest, I have no idea why `mix phoenix.server` just failed to start after pc' reboot(with this `undefined function: MyApp.Endpoint.start_link/0` error). Last time I faced this error I've updated phoenix from 1.1.3 to 1.1.4 and the issue has gone. Yesterday I thought that upgrading to 1.2 is not a solution. I tried to fix all deps to play well with each other; unsuccessfully. Than I reverted all my changes and ran `mix deps.get` again. Phoenix started after that. It's just very strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your server is already started. You just need to kill it and restart using the command **killall beam.smp**